# Php function to return array of variable

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, return

I want to create a simple php function to return an array of variable in wordpress template.

php function in function.php:

```
function testme (){
     $color = 'imaginary'; // or real  
     $y = 'yellow';
     $s = 'silver' ;

     if ($color != 'imaginary') {
            $y = 'golden';
            $s = 'silver' ;
     } else {
            $y = 'yellow';
            $s = 'white' ;
     }

     $wall = array();
     $wall = array ($y ,$s);
     return $wall;
}
```

Called this function in my template like this:

```
<?php 

testme();

?>

<h1>TOP STRIP COLOR IS <?php echo $wall['0'] ?></h1>
<h2>BOTTOM STRIP  COLOR IS <?php echo $wall['1'] ?></h2>
```

But I am not getting array of values in my `<h1>` and `<h2>` tags. Help me to point out my mistake.

Comment: The syntax highlighter shows your error. You're missing a quote: `$s = 'silver ;` <-- here

Comment: Assign the returned value to a variable: `$wall = testme();`

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the return value of the function into variables. Like this:

```
$wall = testme();
```

and then use it:

```
<h1>TOP STRIP COLOR IS <?php echo $wall['0'] ?></h1>
<h2>BOTTOM STRIP  COLOR IS <?php echo $wall['1'] ?></h2>
```

The `$wall` variables you placed inside the `testme` function will only work inside the scope of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Modify `testme()` function to something like this (I removed unused lines and move `$color` to function arguments):

```
function testme ($color) {
    if ($color != 'imaginary') {
        $y = 'golden';
        $s = 'silver';
    } else {
        $y = 'yellow';
        $s = 'white';
    }

    return array($y, $s);
}
```

And, as said in top comments, assign return value to variable and use it:

```
<?php
    $result = testme('imaginary'); // Here we pass argument to function
?>
<h1>TOP STRIP COLOR IS <?php echo $result[0] ?></h1>
<h2>BOTTOM STRIP  COLOR IS <?php echo $result[1] ?></h2>
```